# argument are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

I run my code but show error argument are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range.

Step My code

1. loop file in folder
2. loop sheet Sale,AP,AR,Purchase"
3. copy sheet to new book
4. save and close

My code is as below.

```
Sub CopySheetsToNewWorkbookWithADODB()
    Dim path_Input As String
    Dim path_Output As String
    Dim File_Path As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    
    path_Input = "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\convert file\"
    path_Output = "C:\Users\aa\Desktop\convert file\"
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    ' Loop through all files in a folder
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(path_Input & "*.xlsx")
    
    While fileName <> ""
        ' Check if the filename starts with "10"
        If Left(fileName, 2) = "10" Then
            ' Build the full file path
            File_Path = path_Input & fileName
            
            ' Create a connection to the Excel file
            conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & File_Path & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
            
            ' Create a new workbook
            Dim destWb As Workbook
            Set destWb = Workbooks.Add
            
            ' Loop through the sheets you want to copy
            Dim sheetNames As Variant
            sheetNames = Array("Sale$", "AP$", "AR$", "Purchase$")
            
            For Each sheetName In sheetNames
                ' Check if the sheet exists in the Excel file
                If SheetExists(conn, sheetName) Then
                    ' Create a recordset for the sheet
                    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
                    rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                    
                    ' Copy data from the recordset to the new workbook
                    Dim destWs As Worksheet
                    Set destWs = destWb.Sheets.Add
                    destWs.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
                    
                    ' Close the recordset
                    rs.Close
                End If
            Next sheetName
            
            ' Save the new workbook
            File_Path = path_Output & Left(fileName, 4) & "_Output.xlsx"
            destWb.SaveAs fileName:=File_Path, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
            destWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
            
            ' Close the connection
            conn.Close
        End If
        
        ' Get the next filename
        fileName = Dir
    Wend
    
    Set conn = Nothing ' Force cleanup
    
    MsgBox "Convert Complete"
End Sub

Function SheetExists(ByVal conn As Object, ByVal sheetName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    conn.Execute "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]"
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        SheetExists = True
    Else
        SheetExists = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Now error.
Runtime error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range...'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htbdz.jpg)

error in row
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Please guide me solve it.
Thank you

Comment: Change const to its value. https://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/ado/recordset-cursortype.html

Comment: How to change it?
Please expain to me.

Comment: `rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & sheetName & "]", conn, 3, 1`